# Consuming DynamoDB Streams with AWS Kinesis Data Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am using Kinesis Firehose to consume Dyanamo DB streams through lambda and pushing those records to S3 bucket, Glue job is running every hour to pick the records from S3 , perform deduplication and then finally insert the records to Redshift.

[image]

****Is there any way I can consume the records from Dynamo Streams to 'Kinesis Data Analytics'** and then perform deduplication here and insert the records in Redshift?**

> I have gone through some links https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4582 , [Consume DynamoDB streams in Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436414/consume-dynamodb-streams-in-apache-flink).

- Here it is mentioned that we can use **FlinkKinesisConsumer** to
  consume DynamoDB streams

.
So Can we use this FlinkKinesisConsumer in Kinesis Data Analytics and then consume the Dynamo Stream directly?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, you want to de-duplicate in Kinesis Data Analytics not in AWS Glue?

I think this is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599069/apache-flink-0-10-how-to-get-the-first-occurence-of-a-composite-key-from-an-unbo

Comment: @B.Pesevski, I am looking if Firehose and Glue both can be replaced by 'Kinesis Data Analytics'

Answer (score 2):

**While using Flink as Runtime for Kinesis Data Analytics.**

**sources** : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/how-sources.html

'FlinkKinesisConsumer' can be used to adapt the Dynamo DB Streams (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4582).

**destinations:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/how-sinks.html

'FlinkKinesisFirehoseProducer '  can be used to write into 'Kinesis data firehose'. There is no direct integration with Redshift.